# Qt Editable QGraphicsTextItem validating text and emitting signal on change

Tags: qt, validation, signals, qgraphicsview, qgraphicstextitem

I am really stuck up with a task relating to Qt GraphicsView. Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.
In my QGraphicsView application, I have a few editable QGraphicsTextItems that I have added to the scene. I need the following functionality:

- Setting validator for float so that the user does not by mistake enter a character or new line in that text item.
- Emitting a signal once the text is changed by the user.

Can anyone please suggest how I can implement this in my application? I have tried real hard but I am not able to find anything suitable. If there is any alternative or workaround, I'll be grateful to know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`QGraphicsTextItem` does not support this ability, as I'm sure you have discovered.  So you have a few options:

1. Reimplement `focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent* event)` and/or `keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent* event)` to detect when you validator needs to run.  A `QValidator` can be created as a member of your text class, and queried either when focus is lost and/or a key is pressed (the enter key to signify completion, or on every letter).  Then just create a custom signal for you when deem the editing to have finished or changed.
2. Use a `GraphicsProxyWidget` to hold a 'real' `QLineEdit` for text entry, just set it up with a validator as you would if placing in a traditional GUI form.  You will need to 'forward' the `editingFinished()` or `textEdited(const QString& text)` signal from the `QLineEdit` to your `QGraphicsTextItem`, so you don't have to provide external access to the widget.
3. You could also use the internal `QTextDocument` of the `QGraphicsTextItem`, this is what actually holds and formats the text (access it with `document()`).  However it doesn't support having a `QValidator` installed, so you would have to create a signal-slot loop whereby when the text is changed (signalled by `contentsChanged()`) it's received by the `QGraphicsTextItem`, validated, then either updated/cleared if it fails validation (which will update the `QTextDocument`, and trigger this process again) or ignored if it passes.

Neither is difficult to implement; the first requires more code but will give you more control over the visual appearance of the text box.

Comment: Could [QTextDocument::contentsChanged()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qtextdocument.html#contentsChanged) signal work? You can get the QTextDocument object with [QGraphicsTextItem::document()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicstextitem.html#document). I'm just guessing here.

Comment: @thuga Good idea, it's certainly no more complex than the other approaches.  I've edited it in.

Comment: Thanks guys! really helpful suggestions

Comment: Thank you, comrade, that's it! // Спасибо, товарищ! ^_^

Comment: Thanks, I ran into the same problem... 
Question on option 1:
What's the advantage of using QValidator at all? Why can't I make validation within `keyReleasedEvent`?